# How do I configure sudo in 22.04 for AD group access?

Tags: sudo, 22.04

I have configured sudo access in previous versions of Ubuntu for AD groups.  In 22.04 I get error that user in AD group is not in sudoers file.  I inserted the line %gg_adm_server ALL=(ALL) ALL in sudoers file as usual and it doesn't work.  Has the configuration changed in 22.04?  I have joined the domain using REALMD and can log in as member of AD group, but not sudo.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer was to format the group in sudo as %groupname@DOMAIN.COM.  wouldn't work with lower case domain name, had to be upper case.   YMMV

Answer (score 0):

This answer didn't work on my company domain.

(Note: For me all the groups were showing lowercase and the domain was upper case.)
(Note: Ensure after your COMPANYDOMAINNAME there is 2\ before the group name.)
(Note: If your group has spaces in the name it requires you a \ for each space.)

Also you can use the group (wbinfo -g) or user (wbinfo -u) to get the correct formatting from your domain.

For Root Access:

```
%admin ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%COMPANYDOMAINNAME\\domain\ admins ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

For Sudo Access:

```
%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%COMPANYDOMAINNAME\\domain\ admins ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%COMPANYDOMAINNAME\\workstationadmins ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```